# javascript innerHTML alternative

Tags: javascript, dom

I am using innerHTML to assign updated value to certain elements on a page. However, the innerHTML caused the jquery on the page stopped working, and the css of the page runs out.

So I tried to replace with DOM elements but it's not working. Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks !

```
var names =['id','name','quantity','description']; 
    var len = names.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        var el = document.getElementById(\'product_\'+names[i]+\'_main\');  
        var el2 = document.getElementById(\'product_\'+names[i]+selection);
       if(el.hasChildNodes()) {                                 
         el.replaceChild(el2.firstChild.nodeValue, el.firstChild);
       } 
      if(el && el2) el.innerHTML=el2.innerHTML; /* this part works, but it caused the page CSS to run and jquery no longer working */
      }
```

Comment: As you can see from the highlighting, you've got an syntax error.

Comment: @Bergi in my file there's no syntax error, it was my mistake I minimize some of the lengthy variable. I have edited the code :)

Comment: there should be no backslashes at all, I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
el.replaceChild(el2.firstChild.nodeValue, el.firstChild);
```

Huh, what are you doing there? You can't replace a nodeValue, you can only replace nodes:

```
el.replaceChild(el2.firstChild, el.firstChild);
```

this will move the `firstChild` of `el2` into `el`. If you want to copy it, you'd need to clone it before. If you want all of the children, you'd need to loop over them.

If that `firstChild` is a text node, you can easily (re)set its value, and copy those of el2:

```
if (el.firstChild && el.firstChild.nodeType == 3
  && el2.firstChild && el2.firstChild.nodeType == 3)
    el.firstChild.nodeValue = el2.firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am using el.replaceChild(el2.firstChild, el.firstChild); but the value was not replaced.

However I get the error "el is null" in the FF console. What does that mean and does it mean I cannot replace the value?

Comment: That means `document.getElementById` found nothing - there is no element with the given id. You might need to check that in the if-condition, too.

Comment: yup I did, but it doesn't make a difference, I don't understand how the content wasn't replaced just like how the innerHTML works. It's replacing just a text like "150gm" to "200gm" or "Cold" to "Hot".

Comment: innerHTML gets a html string and parses that, creating lots of new DOM nodes without any additional information like event listeners. This will happen for the whole element, not only for the first text node, and break other elements. To change a text, you should use my second solution.

Comment: many thanks. May I know what does the "3" represents? el.firstChild && el.firstChild.nodeType == 3

Comment: I alert the nodeType and all of them returns "3". When I alert the nodeValue , some of it are blank. Could this be the reason why it is not replaced? But I will need to replace them as well even though they are blank. Thnks again!

Comment: [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType)==3 ensures that it is a textnode. Setting it to blank should work. Could you show us your DOM somewhere, maybe make a jsFiddle?

Comment: many thanks for your help. I have managed to find a solution to the issue. It seems that there are some clashing with other components as well that is why it is not working properly. 
However, without the other components your solution is working fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery already, you can use its .html() method:

```
e1.html( e12.html() );
```

This should do the same as this:

```
el.innerHTML=el2.innerHTML;
```

Comment: It should. So whatever is breaking will still break.

Comment: "the innerHTML caused the jquery on the page stopped working". I kind of went with this assumption, although you may be right in questioning it.

Comment: @Hassan , thanks for your answer. Actually I'm working on Joomla, and the other components which are using Jquery breaks. However for this particular part, it is purely in javascript. Anyway I can put your answer into javascript form to test? 
Thanks !

Comment: @Sylph Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. And you can do whatever you like with the answer.

Comment: @Hassan I meant if we are able to achieve the same thing without using jQuery? Is there other method? Thanks!

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry. (other than the one you already know of course)

Answer (score 0):

If you have JQuery loaded in the page already you can use JQuery selectors and $(element).html() to get the innerHTML.

```
var names =['id', 'name', 'quantity', 'description']; 

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
    var el = $("#product_"+names[i]+"_main");  
    var el2 = $("#product_"+names[i]+selection);

    if (el.children().size() > 0) {                                 
        // Your code here
    } 

    if (el && el2) {
        el.html() = el2.html();
    }
}
```

Untested code.